# Couldn't Resolve Host with Curl

Tags: php, curl

I am using php to pull some json data from my vps.

It has been working like a dream but all of a sudden it stopped working today and just gives me the error of

> Couldn't Resolve Host 'www.myvps.com'()

I was wondering why this is all of a sudden happening, and how i would determine which server is stopping it? I was thinking maybe it was being blocked by the vps, but i own it and i didn't block it..

Here is the php i am using just for reference.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.myvps.com/jsondata.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$body = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);
```

**Edit:** The url is an example url. I have checked the real url and it works fine from browser and ping.

Comment: if the site in your code is real, i can't reach it either from http

Comment: It isn't i changed it. I can both ping and access the page in a browser fine.

Comment: ok but my ping says 100% loss and no http, but could be just me.

Comment: The url mentioned in the above code is not the real one, i changed it for the example.

Answer (score 0):

My web host confirmed there is currently a problem with their uplink that is causing this issue.